# Composer patches cweagans Core module update syntax - one patch not being applied

Tags: composer

I'm using cweagans composer patches: https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches
to patch Drupal 9.x
I've made a patch file.  The first patch applies but I think I have the path wrong for the core module,  layout_builder, which I am trying to patch.  Patch file below.  The patch seems to be completely ignored.  Layout Builder patch is applied to: core/modules/layout_builder/src/Form/OverridesEntityForm.php

```
EDIT:  something is wrong with my patches file.  I moved the patches back into the composer.json file and both worked (with changing "core/lout_builder" to "drupal/core"
When I moved the patches to a file, composer actually re-installed IMCE (from the first patch) but I didn't notice that it didn't re-apply the patch.  So neither patch was working.
{
   "patches": {
     "drupal/imce": {
         "Secuirty isued D9 imcefilefield": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-06-25/ImceFileField-3149697-9-D8.patch"
     },
     "core/layout_builder": {
         "Default region for overridden layout of entity": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-06-18/3053906-11-default-region-value.patch"
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's `drupal/core` and then the patch.

Comment: I.e. replace "core/layout_builder" with "drupal/core" in your code snippet